# Use file:// path in linux to access a file

Tags: linux, file

I've a file that has to be visible across a network of two computers using file:// path. How do I set that up? Thanks.

Comment: Did you just tried to access `file://hostname/path/file.extension`? I don't know, if it works, but worth trying :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `file://` protocol only accesses local filesystem. So you should somehouw mount the file in both computers using NFS or other local sharing system, and then consider it's a local file in both systems.

Comment: In general, `file://` protocol allows accessing remote hosts. Isn't it supported on Linux? URI format is `file://hostname/path/file`. In case o *localhost*, you can omit the hostname and use just `file:///path/file` (note 3 slashes after the protocol).